# Can cryptocurrency charts be estimated using neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, reference-request, prediction

If I were to make a neural network that predicts the value of e.g. Bitcoin tomorrow based on the chart of the last month, would that work? Of course, 100% accuracy cannot be reached, but a success rate over 50% on determining if I should buy or sell Bitcoin could be very profitable. Have there been any attempts to create such neural networks so far?

Comment: Autoregression problem assumes that there is some relationship between the present and the past  values. But in fact, there is too much randomness and unpredictability. I cryptocurrency cannot be predicted with a reasonable accuracy like the stocks market in principle

Comment: The simple answer is : no. Especially crypto that is a vary manipulated market.

Answer (score 1):

There are some academic works on that, but basically what you're asking for is a time-series estimation.

Here's a paper that tries to estimate Bitcoin price, for example: [PAKDD: Forecasting Bitcoin Price with Graph Chainlets](https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10067218).

Comment: To make this answer more useful, it may be a good idea to at least briefly describe their approach in the paper.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very complex task. The price of bitcoin could be affected by NEWs(political desicions, network upgrades, other cryptocurrencies), whales buying and selling crypto, network hashrate.
You can try to search for predictions after lets say after 5 minutes, based on the data inside the orderbook on Exchanges. The market is very volatile, you can make profits of shorter period of time.

https://github.com/Sapphirine/BITCOIN-PRICE-PREDICTION-USING-SENTIMENT-ANALYSIS

https://github.com/miroblog/limit_orderbook_prediction